# Python and files (IO)opening and closing

Tags: python, io, ioerror

I ask about syntax writing in python.
if i have 2 files that i want to open and i make exception like this:

```
try:
    f = open(...)
    ...
    f.close()
    f.open(...) #opens file too
    f.close()
except IOError:
    print("Error with opening file")
finnaly:
    f.close()
```

Is this correct syntax ?

Comment: SO's highlighting should already show you that ``finnaly`` is not correct (it should be ``finally``). Either way, you can just test whether syntax is correct by running it. Is your question how to do this correctly? What exactly are you trying to do, and in how far does your code produce unexpected results? What do you intend ``f.open(...)`` to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File has no .open method that I'm aware

The idiomatic way is using with

```
with open(...) as f1, open(...) as f2:
       ...
```

You can then surround it by try catch as needed. It will close the files at end of with block.